# Is there a "folder fingerprint" to detect if a folder's contents have changed between two points in time? I cannot use FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, filesystemwatcher

I am looking for the fastest way (in C#/ASP.NET) to detect if anything inside a folder has changed between two points in time. I don't need to know the files, total size, or anything else about the folder. I just need to know if anything has changed.

Because I do not have access to the outer scope in which such a folder change detection method would run, I cannot use `FileSystemWatcher`, which must be disposed when no longer needed (it implements `IDisposable` and due to the architecture of what I need I am unable to use it in a practical manner).

It would be ideal if there were some kind of "folder fingerprint" GUID that changed if the folder's contents changed. I could then just compare the last fingerprint GUID to the current fingerprint and return `true` if the two fingerprints were different, indicating something has changed within the folder.

Ideally it would work exactly like the value returned by `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().ManifestModule.ModuleVersionId`, which gives you a "fingerprint" GUID of your application's current build, which then allows you to detect if your application has been recompiled between two points in time.

Something like this:

**Note: "System.IO.GetFolderFingerprint()" is an imaginary method.**

```
public static class FolderChangeChecker
{
    private const string _path = "c:/path/to/folder";    
    private static Guid _originalFingerprint = System.IO.GetFolderFingerprint(_path);    
    public static bool FolderHasChanged()
    {    
        return System.IO.GetFolderFingerprint(_path) != _originalFingerprint;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a way to do this quickly.

Comment: There's no such fingerprint managed by the disk system or operating system. You'd have to create a hash on-demand by looking at the data (or at least the metadata) for all of the files and folders in the given folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I found that the `DateTime` returned by `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime("c:/path/to/folder")` is updated every time a file inside the folder is changed. So, this works perfect for what I needed.

To add to Neil W's answer, theoretically, you could create a hash from the concatenation of the last write time and the folder path, that works without having to enumerate all the files inside the folder.

Comment: It's very strange, because in my case the `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime()` method was returning a new updated time only when some file was added to or removed from the specified folder. But if file was only updated the  `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime()` method returns the same date/time. _The detailed description is in this post:_ [The ‘Directory.GetLastWriteTime()‘ method return the same date/time although a file inside directory is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77351505/6630084). **Therefore, I think the solution provide by @NeilW more correct.**

Comment: @Jackdaw strange, in my environment (windows 11) updating a file also updates the  ‘GetLastWriteTime’ of its folder. I tested it by echoing the DateTime returned by that method to a command prompt every second, and in another window I made changes to a text file located within the folder. Every time I did a save on the text file with Ctrl+S, the DateTime would update

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. Perhaps implementation of the `GetLastWriteTime()` in the Windows 11 and Windows 10 is different.

Answer (score 2):

You could enumerate the files in the directory and build a big string made up of Files' Name, Length, LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks and create a Hash.

```
fileStringSb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

    fileStringSb .Append(fileInfo.Name);
    fileStringSb .Append(fileInfo.Length.ToString());
    fileStringSb .Append(fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc.Ticks.ToString());
}

using (var md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
{
    byte[] filesHash = fingerPrint = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileStringSb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Or do something similar with key properties of the `FileInfo` class. I'm pretty sure that gathering FileInfos is cheaper than enumerating files

Comment: Ya, my original answer just had a remark to encapsulate the actions.  Have updated the answer to use the FileInfo class.  Ta.

Comment: @NeilW I found that concatenating the `DateTime` returned by `File.GetLastWriteTime("c:/path/to/folder")` with the folder path can create a hash that doesn't require enumeration of all the files.

Comment: That makes sense.  An even better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Advance logging IIS lets you record even file system events that you then can  filter your log file for
[advance logging IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging)

Comment: "The IIS Advanced Logging is an extension for Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 is no longer available. We recommend Enhanced Logging for IIS 8.5."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85