# The ‘Directory.GetLastWriteTime()‘ method return the same date/time although a file inside directory is changed

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, ntfs

I'm observed a strange problem when using the [`File.GetLastWriteTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_IO_File_GetLastWriteTime_System_String_) method to get the last write date and time of the specified directory.

Consider the following code:

```cs
// ‘path’ is directory for which need to obtain modification date/time information.
DateTime dtp = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
DateTime dtf = File.GetLastWriteTime(path+@"\log.txt");

Console.WriteLine($"{path}, dir: {dtp:hh:mm:ss.fff}, file: {dtf:hh:mm:ss.fff}");
```

Now, when I update the `log.txt` file, for example, by performing

```
echo some-text >> "log.txt"
```

from the command prompt the `dtf` is updated but the `dtp` doesn't changed.

The specified directory date and time is changed only if I create a **new** file or **delete** some file inside the directory.

Can anyone help me to understand what I missed here?

---

***NOTES:***

1. The same happens when using the [`Directory.GetLastWriteTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getlastwritetime?view=net-7.0) method.
2. Used the Windows 10.
3. The OS doesn't have any registry fixes applied like described in this post:
   [File.GetLastWriteTime seems to be returning 'out of date' value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9992644/6630084)

Comment: I *suspect* that's the expected behavior, although it's not clearly documented. Modifying a file itself doesn't need to change anything in the data structure of the directory containing it. If you just look at "what files are in the directory", nothing has changed.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's what I assumed. And the documentation doesn't have any precise comments about that.
It seems like only specific *Master File Table* ([MFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)) events causing to update the last directory write time and the file I/O operations not one of them. Thanks.

Comment: "NTFS delays updates to the last access time for a file by up to one hour after the last access. NTFS also permits last access time updates to be disabled. Last access time is not updated on NTFS volumes by default." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletime and yeah I suspect @JonSkeet is right as usual. Otherwise what do you expect: the whole recursive chain of folders gets their lasttime updated? Sounds very inefficient.

Comment: @Charlieface: I see. Now I understand that NTFS could not work effectively in this case. Thanks for the reference: WIN32 always have been documented better.

Comment: The [winapi documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataa) makes a much lesser guarantee than you hoped for: *For a directory, the structure specifies when the directory is created. If the underlying file system does not support last write time, this member is zero*.  "underlying file system" is what you need to worry about, don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `LastAccessTime` mentioned in some comment is unrelated to `LastWriteTime`.

With `LastAccessTime` there are no guarantees as to whether it is implemented, how often it gets updated, and how accurate it is.

However, with `LastWriteTime` there are plenty of guarantees, at least on a local NTFS file-system; if it did not work correctly, then lots of other things would not work, including one that we are already quite familiar with: ***Building.*** (Recompiling only those source files that have changed since the last build, which only happened a few seconds ago.)

What is happening here is that windows (or NTFS to be more precise) delays the updating of `LastWriteTime` of a file until that file is closed.  So, `LastWriteTime` may be inaccurate for as long as you are keeping the file open, but once you close that file, it will be updated.

Essentially, you can think of `LastWriteTime` as `LastCloseTime`, or more precisely, `LastCloseTimeAfterOpenedForWriting`.

In the question you say that you update your log.txt file by performing, for example:

```
echo some-text >> "log.txt"
```

Conceptually, this opens `"log.txt"` for appending, writes `some-text` to it, and then closes it. But I said conceptually. If that was in fact happening, then your `LastWriteTime` would be updating correctly, but it doesn't.

What is possibly happening here is that the command processor is applying some optimization where `log.txt` is being kept open across multiple invocations of the `>>` operator.  I do not know this for sure, I am just postulating it.

I do not know exactly what you are doing and how you are doing it, but the solution to your problem is likely to involve somehow making sure that your file has been closed before trying to query its `LastWriteTime`.

Maybe try doing all of your appending to the file via a nested instance of the command processor? Be advised though, that the command processor might also have optimizations for that, too, so if it does not work, you might have to keep trying other possible solutions.

Comment: I have no problem with the `GetLastWriteTime()` when passing a file name to the method. The `echo some-text >> "log.txt"` updates the `LastWriteTime` field absolutely correctly. I also tested this using the `notepad++`. The problem happens when a directory name is passed to the method as the parameter. I noted this in the first sentence of the question.  According to @Charlieface's and @HansPassant's
 comments I understood that this is by design. This implementation helps to not degrade the _NTFS_ performance. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. However: I discovered this information while troubleshooting a `FileSystemWatcher`.  A `FileSystemWatcher` operates on a directory, and is capable of detecting modifications to files within that directory.  So, your solution may involve using a `FileSystemWatcher`, ***and*** making sure that the file is closed after each write.

Comment: I have cases when using the `FileSystemWatcher` is problematic. Like **NAS**, that doesn't work as expected and not stable network connection. Therefore, I'm using some kind of _poling_ (one check per few minutes is enough).  And the `GetLastWriteTime()` method works perfect for files, but not for directories. I thought to simplify the code if it worked for directories too. Thanks you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: If you use polling, and if you keep a `DirectoryInfo` alive during polling, then make sure to invoke `Refresh()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation that I found in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getlastwritetime?view=net-7.0#remarks) is that:

```
This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose 
values may not be continuously updated by the operating system.
```

I think is challenging because a file or a directory may in fact be a virtual one or can be a symlink (in Linux).

Comment: I read the comments carefully. But I think this more indicates the reasons why changes may be reflected with a delay, but does not answer why they are not reflected at all.

Comment: I think "inaccurate value" can be translated also in "not reflected at all"....